# Processing : No valid frames decoded before end of stream

Tags: processing

I am trying to play a video : the video plays, but then I have this error :

`Processing video library using GStreamer 1.16.0 Element: [avdec_prores0] : No valid frames decoded before end of stream`

Here is the code :

```
Movie movie;

public void setup() {
  ...
  movie = new Movie(this, "ani_5.mov");
  movie.loop();
}

public void draw() {
    movie.read();
    image(movie, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Where does the error come from ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the Processing video library can decode Apple ProRes (`avdec_prores0`) nicely.

I recommend taking your original/uncompressed animation and compressing it with the H.264 codec.

Processing should be able to handle that.
(*Processing > Examples > Libraries > Video > Loop/data/transit.mov* is a good example of a video that can play via processing-video)